# Weird BoxLayout painting

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to dysplay an object line by line where each line is an object. Then I use a box Layout but when I do so only the top layer (which is the last object called) is drawed how can I fiw this ?

here is a minimal exemple :

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    }

}

private class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame(){
        setSize(600,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setContentPane(new Container());
    }

}
private class Container extends JPanel {

    public Container(){
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
            add(new Line());
        }

    }

}

private class Line extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.green);

        g.fillRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
    }
}
```

here is what I've got :

[image: WIG]

and what I've expected :

[image: WIE]

Some test (the blue rectangle in the paint method of the JBackPannel class) showed me that somewhere something is drawing a white canvas, but I don't know where and why ...

here is a link to a [minimal exemple](https://www.mediafire.com/file/n8tf4gn4d96gm4u/file)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner post a proper [mre], current code is incomplete. `PerforationLine` class is missing (but don't just add that code, instead just create a program that has a `BoxLayout` and where you try to paint it. 2) Custom painting should be done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` and not `paint(...)` and 3) you shouldn't break the paint chain (i.e. remove `super.paintComponent(...)`) 4) Also, why do you call your classes `JSomething`?

Comment: @Frakcool okay working on minimal reproductible exemple and changing from `pain`t to `paintCompenent` and to answer to 4) : just because I need to name my view class in a clear way then as i'm using swing and all the swing classes are Jsomething then calling my clases JSomething is the clearer and best idea i get if you have a better idea

Comment: You already know you're using Swing, that's the convention for the framework, your classes don't need to follow that convention, it makes it actually more confusing as now you don't know if that `JLine` or whatever class belongs to Swing framework or your own code (even if you know most of the framework classes, there's something you might not know and confuses you)

Comment: let me explain better `JSomething` is the class which handle the vew of the `Something` class and yes it may confuse but as I have no better idea for saying "hey this class is the vew of this part of the model"

Comment: `SomethingView` + `SomethingController` might be a better idea then (IMO), but it's your code and it's up to you. That could even be your company's standards and I'm no one to judge it, just saying it was confusing for me.

Comment: yeah I'll change this later you're somewhat right

Comment: @Frakcool added the minimal exemple

Comment: The minimal example should be posted in the forum. The code in the forum STILL overrides paint(). That was NOT the suggestion you were given. We can't compile that example. There is no main() method. There is no JFrame. We don't see where you add the panel to the frame etc. A painting method should not set the size of a components. It should only use the Graphics object to paint something. The super.paintComponent() should be the first statement, not the last.

Comment: The minimal example should be an [edit] to your question where the code should be in the question, not in an external site. My company's network settings don't allow me to go to the site you posted the code into. The code should be posted in the question as code-formatted text, not in external sites or as images

Comment: @camickr well it looks like I will need a proof because this looks like the minimal exemple I send and this looks like paintComponent ![looks like](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/220613474974171137/740321951658016909/unknown.png)

Comment: @Frakcool okay I took this in note thx

Comment: In your Line class, the fillRect is in relation to the class, not the parent JPanel.  X and Y should both be zero.

Comment: so well it looks like I messed a lot thank @GilbertLeBlanc can you post your comment as a solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom painting is always done relative to the component, not the components location in the parent panel.

So:

```
g.fillRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
```

should be:

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```